# Crash onClick toggle button to disable wifi when battery less 20%

Tags: android, android-wifi, togglebutton, batterylevel

I've tryied this method to disable wifi on click of a toggle button when the battery is less 20% but the application crash on click:

```
public void getRisparmio(View view, Intent intent) {
    // is the toggle on?
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

    IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);

    WifiManager wifiManager;
    if (on && level<20) {
      wifiManager(WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
      wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
    } else {
      wifiManager(WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
      wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What does the logcat say?

Comment: No errors..I'm making the application with my android tablet with AIDE app. I can't see if when i click the logcat print some error i think.. But the code is correct.

Comment: The concept is correct.. if on and the level is less 20% then disable wifi..else if the button is off active wifi..but nothing..crash.

Comment: When you get a crash, an exception is printed into the logcat. What does it say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're missing a couple of = signs in your code. Try using:

```
if (on && level<20) {
  wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
  wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
} else {
  wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
  wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: It's the same :( crash. FATAL EXCEPTION: main, Could not find a method getRisparmio(View) in the activity..

Comment: @user2508402 If this is your onclick method, you aren't allowed to have an intent argument in the parameters. It should only be View.

Comment: mmh, ok.. But i have to "insert" this intent to do what i want.. Is there another way?

Comment: @user2508402 You'll have to get the battery level from a utility method or class, which you'll have to create. No way around the Single View Parameter only rule in this case.

Comment: Ah ok..so i need to create a method for example and the how can i implement this method inside the condition?

Comment: @user2508402 You can't. There can be only one parameter, and it must be View

Comment: So my idea it's impossible to realize?

Comment: @user2508402 No, you'll just have to figure out another way to do it. Probably register a BroadcastReceiver and set a flag in a singleton somewhere. when the battery is low enough, and then check that flag in the onclick method.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass only View as an argument. Intent is not allowed.